# request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; it will throw an exception in a same method for second time

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void sendSingleSMS(String username, String password, String senderid, String mobileNo, String message)
{
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        String smsservicetype = "singlemsg"; //For single message.

        String query = "username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username) + "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password) + "&smsservicetype=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(smsservicetype) + "&content=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message) + "&mobileno=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mobileNo) + "&senderid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(senderid);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;            
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);           
        dataStream.Close();           
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();            
        String Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        //byteArray.clear(0);
        //byteArray.length = 0;
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        //request.ContentType = null;

        request.Abort();
}
```

Please Help us from this error ...

I want to reuse a WebRequest object so that cookies and session would be saved for later request to the server. Below is my code. If i use Post function twice on the second time at

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
it will throw an exception

This property cannot be set after writing has started!
But as you can see

dataStream.Close();
Should close the writing process! Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep cookies (and thus the session too), you want to use HttpWebRequest and its [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

First you create it:

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
```

Then you assign it to your request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

Then you do whatever you want (send request, get response, process response ...). And then you can create another request and "reuse" the cookieJar:

```
HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
request2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

This second request will use the same cookieJar that will contain cookies from the first request-response.